# Android file copying caused java.io.IOException: File descriptor closed

Tags: android, linux, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

My app copies a bunch of files and the request comes in as a list. I have a ContentProvider implemented so I need to copy a file and register it with my file provider. I have tried two things - spinning off an AsyncTask for each file copy and spinning off one AsyncTask to handle all of them. The problem I'm facing is that with multiple AsyncTasks the phone really slows down for a second or two. However when handling files one by one, I get the IOException - file descriptor closed:

```
                D  .doInBackground() - outputUri is /photo/20150602004304409
                D  .doInBackground() - outputUri is /photo/20150602004304421
                D  .doInBackground() - outputUri is /photo/20150602004304423
                D  .doInBackground() - outputUri is /photo/20150602004304426
                D  .doInBackground() - outputUri is /photo/20150602004304428

                E  java.io.IOException: File descriptor closed
                E      at libcore.io.Posix.writeBytes(Native Method)
                E      at libcore.io.Posix.write(Posix.java:223)
                E      at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:313)
                E      at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:497)
                E      at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:186)
```

This is my code:

```
 Uri outputUri = Uri.parse(String.format(path, context.getPackageName()));
 mOutputUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(outputUri, null);
 if (AndroidHelper.isGingerBreadMR1()) {
     execute();
 } else {
     executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
 }
```

<...>

```
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        boolean error = false;
        Log.d(TAG,".doInBackground() - outputUri is "+mOutputUri.getPath());
        try {
            inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mInputUri);
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getMediaFileDescriptor(mOutputUri);
            if (fileDescriptor != null) {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ".doInBackground - exception caught while copying the file",e);
            error = true;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, ".doInBackground - exception caught while closing input stream",e);
                error = true;
            }
        }
        return (error) ? mInputUri : mOutputUri;
```

getMediaFileDescriptor looks like this:

```
private FileDescriptor getMediaFileDescriptor(Uri outputUri) {
    try {
        return mContext.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(outputUri, "w")
                .getFileDescriptor();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, ".getMediaFileDescriptor() - Error opening media output stream", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the same file descriptor again and again. File descriptor becomes invalid after you close the stream.

Comment: Also share the logcat output

Comment: The output uri is a new uri each time - I've checked that. Also doing a simple toString on the fileDescriptor object returns different values... Unless contentresolver reuses file descriptors under the covers? Is there any way I can check/protect against that?

Comment: added the logs for the path output

Comment: Just to check, dont close the streams. See what happens.

Comment: same problem - i guess something else closes the descriptor..

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem,it's not good but you must Flush the stream before close it.

```
while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                outputStream.Flush();
            }
```

my problem solved by this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should also be sure to call `.close()` on the `ParcelFileDescriptor` returned by `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor` when you are done with it.